# Performing multiple "Closest Facilities" analyses for multiple feature classes

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst, error-000735

I am trying to calculate network distance from 10 points within 896 polygons "SA1s" (a total of 8960 facilities), each to ten points within 186 polygons "DZNs" (a total of 1860 incidents). I would like to iterate over each of the 896 facility groups (each has it's own feature class, containing 10 points (I would undertake some post-processing of these feature classes, deleting the main outputs with each one.

The iteration is not particularly problematic, but I'm having a problem with the actual python script running over a single iteration.

I set up a script in Model Builder on a test set of data (10 facilities from one SA1 to 10 incidents from one DZN) and ran it - it ran perfectly. I then deleted the outputs and exported the model to a python script, shown below:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Network")


# Local variables:
Incidents = "in_memory\\{DC034A5A-77FD-4B9E-BD36-ECDE5ABD576B}"
Facilities = "in_memory\\{0AA3C7A5-47AA-494D-B97E-6C5A25C7F522}"
in_memory = "in_memory"
Point_Barriers = "in_memory\\{DDEAEEC2-AAD9-4B99-9D69-1020AEEF8B6F}"
Line_Barriers = "in_memory\\{C7F6D7A5-B9FB-447B-8373-E98398408F2C}"
Polygon_Barriers = "in_memory\\{40ABDBEB-B48B-4C95-8354-9C3DFB60EDB9}"
Attribute_Parameter_Values = "in_memory\\{D84163A6-7A47-419B-B8FF-79420ABC0651}"
DZN_Test_Points =    "C:\\Users\\xgoldie\\Desktop\\ModeShare_Study\\Mode_Share_Study.gdb\\DZN_Test_Points"
SA1_Test_Points = "C:\\Users\\xgoldie\\Desktop\\ModeShare_Study\\Mode_Share_Study.gdb\\SA1_Test_Points"
ACT_Road_Network_ND_nd = "C:\\Users\\xgoldie\\Desktop\\ModeShare_Study\\ACT_Road_Network_ND.nd"
Mode_Share_Study_gdb = "C:\\Users\\xgoldie\\Desktop\\ModeShare_Study\\Mode_Share_Study.gdb"

# Process: Find Closest Facilities
arcpy.FindClosestFacilities_na(DZN_Test_Points, SA1_Test_Points, "Meters", ACT_Road_Network_ND_nd, Mode_Share_Study_gdb, "Routes_Test", "Directions_Test", "ClosestFacilities_Test", "10", "", "TRAVEL_TO", "", "NOT_USED", "GEO_LOCAL", "ALLOW_UTURNS", Point_Barriers, Line_Barriers, Polygon_Barriers, "Minutes", "Minutes", "Meters", "Meters", "NO_HIERARCHY", "", Attribute_Parameter_Values, "", "20 Kilometers", "\"ACT_Road_Network\" #;\"ACT_Road_Network_ND_Junctions\" #", "TRUE_LINES_WITH_MEASURES", "10 Meters", "NO_DIRECTIONS", "", "Miles", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "NO_SAVE_OUTPUT_LAYER")
```

I then attempted to run it again from IDLE, and it failed. Giving me the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xgoldie\Desktop\SCRIPTS\networkanalyst.py", line 30, in <module>
    arcpy.FindClosestFacilities_na(DZN_Test_Points, SA1_Test_Points, "Meters", ACT_Road_Network_ND_nd, Mode_Share_Study_gdb, "Routes_Test", "Directions_Test", "ClosestFacilities_Test", "10", "", "TRAVEL_TO", "", "NOT_USED", "GEO_LOCAL", "ALLOW_UTURNS", Point_Barriers, Line_Barriers, Polygon_Barriers, "Minutes", "Minutes", "Meters", "Meters", "NO_HIERARCHY", "", Attribute_Parameter_Values, "", "20 Kilometers", "\"ACT_Road_Network\" #;\"ACT_Road_Network_ND_Junctions\" #", "TRUE_LINES_WITH_MEASURES", "10 Meters", "NO_DIRECTIONS", "", "Miles", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "NO_SAVE_OUTPUT_LAYER")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\na.py", line 2595, in FindClosestFacilities
    raise e
ExecuteError: A geoprocessing error occurred.
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000735: Input Rows: Value is required
Failed to execute (GetCount).
Failed to execute (FindClosestFacilities).
```

Does anyone why this is occuring, and how to fix it?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but can you really have those {DC034A5A-77FD-4B9E-BD36-ECDE5ABD576B} for defining variable names in Python code? Perhaps replace them with a string ("temp_layername"). I would recommend opening manually a GP tool in Network Analyst toolbox > define the parameters > run it > make sure it worked fine > go to Results window > right-click > Copy as Python Snippet > try this chunk of code. Should help if when exporting from ModelBuilder some of the parameters value gone or get invalid.

Comment: I've fixed that component, but the problem now is the temporary facilities layer from the first iteration prevents me from doing the next round: Traceback (most recent call last):       
    ExecuteError: A geoprocessing error occurred.
    Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
    ERROR 000725: Output Layer: Dataset OrigInputFacilitiesLayer already exists.
Failed to execute (MakeFeatureLayer).
Failed to execute (FindClosestFacilities).

Comment: just use the arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True. Or delete objects first before trying to write them over :)

Comment: Yes I threw the error code into Google and found the overwrite answer last night - working swimmingly now! Thanks very much for your help

Comment: I have wrapped up my comments as an answer you can vote and acccept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can name your feature classes as those `{DC034A5A-77FD-4B9E-BD36-ECDE5ABD576B}` for defining variable names in Python code. You should perhaps replace them with a string ("temp_layername"). I would recommend opening manually a GP tool in Network Analyst toolbox > define the parameters > run it > make sure it worked fine > go to Results window > right-click > Copy as Python Snippet > try this chunk of code. Should help if when exporting from ModelBuilder some of the parameters value gone or get invalid.

If having troubles overwriting existing objects, use `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True` for the [env](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00210000001m000000) settings.

Comment: Unfortunately the snippet tool doesn't work as a solution for Network Analyst, because the results aren't saved to the geoprocessing results window when you run the Closest Facility tool.

Comment: This is why it might be good to run the GP tool http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004800000008000000 (Make Closest Facility Layer).